# How to reduce the distance between tooltip and datapoint or cursor

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I want to reduce the distance between tooltip and actual data point or cursor in dygraph.

Tried this

```js
g = new Dygraph(
  document.getElementById("demodiv_one_right"), [
    [1, 10, 100],
    [2, 20, 80],
    [3, 50, 60],
    [5, 70, 80],
    [6, 10, 90],
    [7, 20, 60],
    [8, 40, 80]
  ],

  {
    labels: ['Date', 'Y1', 'Y2'],
    ylabel: 'Primary y-axis',
    y2label: 'Secondary y-axis',
    legend: 'follow',
    axes: {
      y2: {
        // set axis-related properties here
        valueRange: [0, 200],
        independentTicks: true
      }
    }
  },

);

function update(el) {
  g.updateOptions({
    fillGraph: el.checked
  });
}
```

```css
.dygraph-legend {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Multiple y-axes</title>
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.0/dygraph.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.0/dygraph.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="demodiv_one_right" style="width: 640; height: 350; border: 1px solid black"></div>

  <input type=checkbox id="check" onChange="update(this)"><label for="check"> Fill?</label>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

I am trying to place tool tip so that it should follow cursor.

Does anyone have idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've added an extra div to contain the label. Created a CSS variable for the mouse position and keep it up to date with an eventlistener. I use that in the css for the label to position it. Then use the [labelsDiv](https://dygraphs.com/options.html#labelsDiv) parameter of Dygraph. And I leave the `legend` parameter to the default *onmouseover*.

```js
let g = new Dygraph(
  document.getElementById("demodiv_one_right"), [
    [1, 10, 100],
    [2, 20, 80],
    [3, 50, 60],
    [5, 70, 80],
    [6, 10, 90],
    [7, 20, 60],
    [8, 40, 80]
  ], {
    labels: ['Date', 'Y1', 'Y2'],
    labelsDiv: document.getElementById("demodiv_one_right_label"),
    ylabel: 'Primary y-axis',
    y2label: 'Secondary y-axis',
    axes: {
      y2: {
        // set axis-related properties here
        valueRange: [0, 200],
        independentTicks: true
      }
    }
  },
);

function update(el) {
  g.updateOptions({
    fillGraph: el.checked
  });
}

let root = document.documentElement;
root.addEventListener(
  "mousemove",
  event => {
    root.style.setProperty('--mouse-x', event.clientX + "px");
    root.style.setProperty('--mouse-y', event.clientY + "px");
  }
);
```

```css
:root {
  --mouse-x: 0px;
  --mouse-y: 0px;
}

#demodiv_one_right_label {
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--mouse-x);
  top: var(--mouse-y);
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.0/dygraph.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.0/dygraph.min.js"></script>
<div id="demodiv_one_right_label"></div>
<div id="demodiv_one_right" style="width: 640; height: 350; border: 1px solid black"></div>
<input type=checkbox id="check" onChange="update(this)"><label for="check"> Fill?</label>
```